# Laravel setting up to Multi login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in this framework i want to use multi login and i have `userAccount` model with define table with `userAccount` names.

in this below `Route` i want to use `userAccount` model and table for login

```
Route::post('accountAuth', array('as'=>'accountAuth', 'before'=>'csrf', function(){
    if ( Auth::attempt( array( 'username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password') ) ) ){
        Return View::make('layouts.account.main');
    }
    else
        return Redirect::route('userLogin')
                ->with('message','ERROR')
                ->withInput();
}));
```

how to do this action for enable or using multi login?

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'multi login'? Do you want to log in multiple users with one set of credentials? I'm not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: Or did you mean multiple type of users? admin, mod and normal user? if so I'd suggest checking out Sentry. Otherwise elaborate what you're asking.

Comment: @DerLola , @nCore i want to use that for admin user in `site.com/admin` and `site.com/login`. admin table is `user` and normal user table is `siteUsers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multi login pretty easily if you use a controller to help with your task:

```
class LogonController extends Controller {

    public function adminLogin()
    {
        return $this->login('Admin');
    }

    public function accountLogin()
    {
        return $this->login('User');
    }

    public function login($model)
    {
        if ($user = $model::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first())
        {
            if (Hash::check($user->password, Input::get('password')))
            {
                Auth::login($user);

                return Redirect::to('/');
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Wrong password.');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withMessage('User not found.');
        }
    }

}
```

Then you just need to create different routes for it:

```
Route::post('admin', 'LogonController@adminLogin');

Route::post('login', 'LogonController@accountLogin');
```